# Execute multiple commands to Putty - the send command should work on the data got fom executing first command

Tags: java, putty

after executing a command got some set of files having similar data.
so using another command I want fore filtered data.

I have tried using

```
********/path/** && cat *****

*******/path/** && grep -r "****"
```

i expect the data should be among the data got from the previous command.
suppose we got data as 4 files after exectuing

```
grep -r "acs_txn_id : 3*****-c"

a1.txt
a2.txt
a3.txt
a4.txt
```

I expect the output as

```
a1.txt
a3.txt
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java and PuTTY? It looks like a plain shell question to me – Though to be honest, I do not really understand what you want.

Comment: Welcome to _Stack Overflow_. Did you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)? Did you visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)? If you want to get help with your problem, I recommend doing so. Hopefully you will learn how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).